# OpenLayers popup FramedCloud in mobile

Tags: openlayers-2, popup, mobile

How I can use the pop-up window in OpenLayers on mobile? I have implemented the `FramedCloud` popup on my website, but when I open my web browser on a mobile device, the popup window does not seem to work or listen to any open action open.